# Iterate a list inside an object with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to iterate a list of objects, which each one has a list of String inside, but I'm having trouble with it.

I tried to use dynamic blocks, but I'm getting the error **Unsupported block type**.

I'm declaring my variable that way:

```
variable "test" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    nicknames = list(string)
  }))

  default = [
    {
      name = "Phoebe"
      nicknames = ["Pheebs", "Phalange"]
    },
    {
      name = "Chandler"
      nicknames = ["Chanchan", "Mr. Bing"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my resource is that way:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  for_each = {for i, v in var.teste:  i => v}
  name             = each.value.name
  nicknames  = each.value.nicknames
  dynamic "nicknames_list" {
    for_each = [each.value.nicknames]
    content {
      opn = nicknames_list.value
    }
  }
}
```

How can I iterate an object with a list inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can to **flatten** your `test` into more `for_each` friendly structure:

```
variable "test" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    nicknames = list(string)
  }))

  default = [
    {
      name = "Phoebe"
      nicknames = ["Pheebs", "Phalange"]
    },
    {
      name = "Chandler"
      nicknames = ["Chanchan", "Mr. Bing"]
    }
  ]
}


locals {

  test_flat = merge([
      for idx, val in var.test:
        {
          for name, nickname in val.nicknames:         
              "${idx}-${name}-${nickname}" => {
                  name = name
                  nickname = nickname
                }
        }          
    ]...)
}
```

which will result in `test_flat` of

```
{
  "0-0-Pheebs" = {
    "name" = 0
    "nickname" = "Pheebs"
  }
  "0-1-Phalange" = {
    "name" = 1
    "nickname" = "Phalange"
  }
  "1-0-Chanchan" = {
    "name" = 0
    "nickname" = "Chanchan"
  }
  "1-1-Mr. Bing" = {
    "name" = 1
    "nickname" = "Mr. Bing"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what do you want to do in your `aws_lambda_function` as attributes such as `nicknames` or `nicknames_list` **are incorrect**. But you could use the flatten list (example only, as your `aws_lambda_function` is incorrect to begin with)

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  
  for_each                 = local.test_flat

  function_name            = each.value.name
  # some other attribute   = each.value.nickname
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
The way that I was using the dynamic indeed was incorrect, I adjusted and worked with the environment variables block, but I need the "nickname" information on that block, and on the function_name, so didn't work how I expected.

Your answer didn't work for me, I'm getting the "Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple"." error.

Comment: @G.Falcão Did you forget to put `...` in the merge. This is impotant.

Comment: Yes, I removed it, when I put it back worked like a charm! Thanks a lot, Marcin, I'm a newbie on tf, I have to read more. Thx a lot again.